# Filter getent passwd output with SSSD

Tags: ldap, users, groups, filter, sssd

I am using ldap_access_filter in sssd.conf in order to limit access to users that are in a specific ldap group. However, when I do a "getent passwd" I still get a full list of the ldap users.

How can I limit the output to only the users of this specific group (preferably with SSSD)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option to achieve this is to create an LDAP filter string to be used by the `ldap_user_search_base` config parameter (syntax: `search_base[?scope?[filter][?search_base?scope?[filter]]*]`).

This must be a valid [RFC 2254](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2254.txt) filter, and will likely somehow incorporate your `ldap_access_filter` into the `ldap_user_search_base`.

The reason for this is that applying the access filter is a second step after checking if an account exists, which will not be done by `getent`.

Comment: More specifically, it's a check implemented by the PAM module which has nothing to do with NSS. (which `getent` consults)

Comment: I used the ldap_user_search_base successfully (incorporated my memberOf filter) but I still get a complete list of users with getent passwd. Any clues?

Comment: Make sure to remove the cache and restart sssd after implemeting the filter.

Comment: I have deleted the files in /var/lib/sss/db/, also the cache_credentials is set to false and the nscd is stopped. Maybe is something wrong with my /etc/ldap.conf and /etc/openldap/ldap.conf settings? (I am using SUSE)

Comment: I checked today and the extra entries were gone, even though I deleted / disabled all the cache yesterday... Probably I missed something. Anyway, now it works.Thanks for your help people =)

Comment: Regarding the cache: Deleting the cache should work with `sss_cache -U` (invalidate all users). If you have `nscd` running alongside, you might need to invalidate that cache as well (`nscd -i passwd`).